# How to build a bundle without embedding the other installers?

Tags: wix, burn

This works for me

```
<ExePackage Id="Netfx35"
    Cache="no"
    Compressed="yes"
    PerMachine="yes"
    Permanent="yes"
    Vital="yes"
    InstallCommand="/q /norestart /lang:ENU"
    RepairCommand="/q /norestart /lang:ENU"
    UninstallCommand="/q /norestart /lang:ENU"
    DetectCondition="DotNetFramework35SPInstallRegValue"
    SourceFile="embed\DotNetFX35SP1\dotnetfx35.exe" />
```

But it embeds the .NET installer into the bundle package. I want to keep it as a separate file. I'm trying to use the Payload tag, but I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace Compressed="yes" with Compressed="no" on your Bundle authoring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the [Container](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/container.html) element:

`Type` attribute:

> Indicates whether the container is "attached" to the bundle executable
>   or placed external to the bundle executable as "detached". If this
>   attribute is not specified, the default is to create a detached
>   container.